# TCP packet issue with 802.11ac but not with 802.11n on an Android Nexus 6

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, wireshark, tcpip

I have an Android Nexus 6 that connects to my computer via an ad-hoc network.

When my phone connects to the 802.11n card ([TP-LINK 300Mbps Wireless N](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/?categoryid=212)), the bytes are sent with no issue; verified with Wireshark.

When my phone connects to the 802.11ac card ([ASUS PCE-AC56 802.11ac](http://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCEAC56/)), there seem to be many packet issues; verified with Wireshark as well.

The same program is running on my computer (reading in the bytes) and the same program is running on my phone (sending the bytes). With the 802.11n card it works fine, but with the 802.11ac card it does not.

Thoughts?

Wireshark capture files can be seen [at the following Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o34hh9dafya379r/AADreJWdUL7bSrsQCJDV24dTa?dl=0).

Comment: I looked at one of those pcaps and it looked like an Ethernet-layer capture, not an 802.11 monitor-mode capture. I doubt the cause of the problem will be visible at the Ethernet layer. You probably need to do an 802.11 monitor mode capture (from another machine) to see the cause of the problem.